# Apple Game Center api

Tags: iphone, center, gamekit

I'm having trouble finding the GameKit api that contains the Game Center Reference.

Apple Game Center is a social networking platform new to iOS. It's described here: [What's New in iOS4][1]

The GameKit iOS reference is here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/index.html

You have to click the `iOS SDK beta` tab in the main page.

Answer (score 2):

GameCenter API is available in iOS 4.1 API which is still in private beta (available on [dev center](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action) if you log in there with your apple developer account) and is under NDA. You can discuss it in apple dev forums.