# Multiplayer without a server on IOS

Tags: asp.net, ios, web-services, ios5, multiplayer

So I am writing an app for the IOS family. The app needs to find 2 people whom are "looking for an opponent". And save their information so they can communicate later. Is there an APi or framework made for this type of looking, hosted on some universal server doing this for me? Or must I host a server and make a list of people and pair them up myself with some type of webservice? Also If you have a better idea at how to do this please let me know. I am new to the multipler IOS scene so I could be going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the IOS 5 [Game Center API](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/gamecenter/) to help match players who are running IOS 5 and later.

According to [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3479031/141172) it's also available in IOS 4.1, though I cannot confirm that.

Comment: THank you, but I have a follow up question then, can you match players without having to bring up the gamecenter interface?

Comment: I don't know, but I know it can be done.  One of my favorite games, Air Wings, does just that.  Suggest you post a new question.